# How to create a memory dump of an android emulator?

Tags: android, memory, android-emulator, android-memory

I have an android emulator, and I want to create a RAM (memory) dump. I already tried Fridump (which dumps a specific process). It returns a bunch of  (****_dump.data) files. I came across some documentations on how to use LiME, with goldfish. But all these documentations are outdated. To keep my question short: I want to extract or dump the RAM of an android emulator device, and then analyze that dump file with volatility.

Specs:
API Level: 30
ABI list: x86
Android: 11
Device is already rooted ;)

I already tried Fridump, i tried to use LiME and to compile the kernel, but again, all those documentations are outdated and don't seem to be working anymore.

Comment: Would [dumpsys](https://developer.android.com/tools/dumpsys#ViewingAllocations) help?

Comment: @Onik This will only show me details in a txt file. But I am interested in the actual dump of the memory